# Moving object around and later calling a method that consumes the object's self yields "cannot move out of borrowed content"

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I know there are 1000 questions about this, but it seems none of the ones I read fit this issue.

What I'm doing is, at a certain function I'm creating a RusotoFuture (from the rusoto_s3 crate):

```
fn execute(&mut self, s3: &S3Client) -> (i64, RusotoFuture<GetObjectOutput, GetObjectError>) {
   ...
   let dl = s3.get_object(GetObjectRequest{
        ...
        ..Default::default()
    });
   return (sz, dl);
```

I return this object, and store it:

```
fn handle_op(&mut self, input: u64) {
   ...
   let (sz, dl) = op.execute( &self.s3.as_ref().unwrap() );
   self.pending = Some(dl);
```

Later I want to call sync on this object from the handle_op function, the problem is the signature consumes self (https://rusoto.github.io/rusoto/rusoto_core/struct.RusotoFuture.html#method.sync):

```
pub fn sync(self) -> RusotoResult<T, E>
```

And handle_op takes `&mut self`, so I don't have the ownership of the RusotoFuture.

```
fn execute(&mut self, req: &mut RusotoFuture<GetObjectOutput, GetObjectError>) {
   ...
   let result = req.sync().expect("could not download");
```

Calling with:

```
op.execute(self.pending.as_mut().unwrap() );
```

And the error:

```
let result = req.sync().expect("could not head");
             ^^^ cannot move out of borrowed content
```

How can I achieve this? Is there anyway I can force some unsafe mechanism to take ownership of it?
I'm also looking at Box, but I'm getting the same error. It's likely I'm not using it correctly, though.

Comment: It may very well be that `op.execute(self.pending...);` borrows the `req` so that you can't consume it later on by calling `req.sync()`. But without [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 1):

The signature consumes itself because it doesn't make that much sense to keep a Future after it has resolved. So you shouldn't be calling sync on a reference. But it isn't clear from your question what is calling what:

```
let result = req.sync().expect("could not download");
let result = req.sync().expect("could not head");
         ^^^ cannot move out of borrowed content
```

Are those the same line and you changed the string or are they different lines e.t.c?

But I can still try to answer.

```
let dl = s3.get_object(GetObjectRequest{
    ...
    ..Default::default()
});
```

the `RusotoFuture` returned by `get_object` is not a reference, so

```
fn handle_op(&mut self, input: u64) {
   ...
   let (sz, dl) = op.execute( &self.s3.as_ref().unwrap() );
   self.pending = Some(dl);
```

has a consumable d1, even if it takes `&mut self` as an argument.
So you should change the execute function from

```
fn execute(&mut self, req: &mut RusotoFuture<GetObjectOutput, GetObjectError>) {...}
```

to

```
fn execute(&mut self, req: RusotoFuture<GetObjectOutput, GetObjectError>) {...}
```

and then call it as

```
op.execute( self.pending.take() );
```

Is there any reason that isn't possible in your setup?